# Angularjs avoid scientific notation for number filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scientific-notation

I need to print very small numbers for my app.  I prefer if they were all displayed in decimal format.  Is there a way to do this with the angularjs number filter or do I have to write my own or modify the existing one somehow?

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/2386/

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.MyNum1 = 0.000001;
   $scope.MyNum2 = 0.0000001;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Small Number: {{MyNum1 | number:8}}<br/>
  Very Small Number: {{MyNum2 | number:8}}
</div>
```

Inconsistent Output

```
Small Number: 0.00000100
Very Small Number: 1e-7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't fully tested this and I'm not sure how to get this working on jsfiddle, but this seems to be working for the time being.

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('decimalFormat', function () {
  return function (text) {
    return parseFloat(text).toFixed(20).replace(/0+$/,'');
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Small Number: {{MyNum1 | number:8 | decimalFormat}}<br/>
  Very Small Number: {{MyNum2 | number:8 | decimalFormat}}
</div>
```

**Edit after Langdon's comment, added commas:**

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('decimal', function () {
  return function (text) {
      var parts = parseFloat(text).toFixed(8).split('.');
      parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      return parts.join('.');
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.MyNum1 = 0.12345678912;
  $scope.MyNum2 = 0.000000100001;
  $scope.MyNum3 = 0;
  $scope.MyNum3 = 1123123.05;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Small Number: {{MyNum1 | decimal}}<br/>
  Very Small Number: {{MyNum2 | decimal}}<br/>
  Zero: {{MyNum3 | decimal}}<br/>
  Million: {{MyNum4 | decimal}}<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea, that's about right, except you no longer need the `number:8` filter and you should probably simplify 'decimalFormat' to just 'decimal'.  The only thing you lose (that Angular's number filter does for you) is i18n.  http://jsfiddle.net/fH9bM/

Comment: Your edited version introduced an extra closing brace in the filter function, but the edit for that is too trivial to be allowed.  I also added a parameter for the number of places for the `toFixed()` call in my own version copied from this, but I think that might change the intent of your function too much to suggest as an edit here.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to write your own since the existing filter in the source doesn't handle large decimal places (see `formatNumber` in the [filters.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js)).  Ultimately the problem is that `toString` is called to display the number in your HTML.  More ideally, `toFixed` could be called, but that gets tricky because you have to figure out the length of the decimals.

```
console.log(0.000001);
 > 0.000001
console.log(0.0000001);
 > 1e-7
console.log(0.0000001.toFixed(20));
 > 0.00000010000000000000
```

Here's a quick hack:

```
console.log(0.0000001.toFixed(20).replace(/0+$/, ''));
 > 0.0000001
```

So your custom filter could be as simple as that.  I'd recommending filing an issue on GitHub though.

Answer (score 1):

This was made to return **large** numbers as decimal strings, but it works as well for small ones-

```
Number.prototype.noExponents= function(){
    var data= String(this).split(/[eE]/);
    if(data.length== 1) return data[0]; 

    var  z= '', sign= this<0? '-':'',
    str= data[0].replace('.', ''),
    mag= Number(data[1])+ 1;

    if(mag<0){
        z= sign + '0.';
        while(mag++) z += '0';
        return z + str.replace(/^\-/,'');
    }
    mag -= str.length;  
    while(mag--) z += '0';
    return str + z;
}

var n=1e-7;
n.noExponents();
returned value: (String) '0.0000001';
```

Comment: Have you updated this function in meantime? Or you are still using this one?