# AngularJS showing scientific number in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API which returns a float to my Angular app using $http.

```
// Send the API request and handle the response/error
        $http( request ).then( function( response ) {
            console.log( response.data.pension.amount );
        }
```

In the console, `response.data.pension.amount` is as it should be, and shows 4500.00, but if I add it to my template (i.e. `{{ data.pension.amount }}`) it actually shows in the browser as `4.208266786607881e-8`.

I'm stuck as to how I can actually get this value to display properly on my page.

I'm trying to use this with the Angular currency filter, which displays as $0.00 because of the scientific number format.

### Edit: Another example

The API returns the following:

```
{
  ...
  "pension": {
    "amount": "4500.00",
  }
  ...
}
```

If I use `typeof` in the console, I get string, and if I console.log pension or pension.amount, I see 4500.00 as a string.

But, if I console.log just response.data, in the pension object it no longer shows `"4500.00"`. Instead it shows `4.208266786607881e-8`.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with it being in a nested object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116268/angularjs-avoid-scientific-notation-for-number-filter

Comment: Doesn't work. It displays 0.00000004 instead of 4500.00

Answer (score 0):

<strike>JavaScript has a few functions which can help you format floating point numbers for display, but they tend to require a lot of fiddling in order to get right.</strike>

I wrote this little component to handle explicit scientific notation formatting:

Demo: http://mobiusklein.github.io/ng-scientific-notation/

Source: https://github.com/mobiusklein/ng-scientific-notation

Edit - Reading Comprehension Failure

Scientific notation isn't your issue then. It's that your data structure is being altered at some point between being set in your `$http` callback and your template being updated. To understand this problem, we'll need to also see how you're putting `response.data` in the scope you're binding to this template.

Are there any other components which watch that value or a related value which may update them?

Comment: My problem is that Angular is displaying the scientific notation, and I want to use the actual number rounded to 2 decimal places. The weird thing is that the number is returned as a string "4500.00" from the API but Angular isn't treating it as a string and is instead using the scientific notation - which I don't want.